# adding more/different text into a textarea when click a button in java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

[screen print PART II](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pdey9.png)[print screen PART I[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AuGpR.png)I want to add more players into the textArea when I click the Add Players button. I could add only one player but when add another one it replaces the first one, what should i do to add as many players as i want?

here is the code:

```
while(true){

       if(event.getSource() == addPlayerButton){
          string = nameTextField.getText();
          outputTextField.append("\n Added player: " + string + " has $" ); 
          nameTextField.setText("");

       }
       break;
       }
```

thanks!

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1):

> A `TextField` object is a text component that allows for the editing of a **single line** of text. you can use JTextArea or  remove the `'\n'`

```
outputTextField.append("Added player: " + string + " has $" );
```

Comment: Im using the JTextArea class, "outputTextField" is just the name i picked, please look at the code i'll provide in a minute.

Comment: couldn't upload the code for formatting issue and i'm attaching a print screen.

Comment: @Ahmed Hadi   from the code contained in print screen I cant locate the problem, it would be better if you can present complete code.

Comment: the other part of the code has been provided. thanks a lot!

Comment: @Ahmed Hadi  comment or remove *outputTextArea.setText(...)* in method *actionPerformed* of *MyListener Class*

Comment: it worked! love you man! how can i make you take points of this advice ?

Comment: can you provide some explanation about why it worked? since i need to print "NEW GAME!" when I click on the "New Game" button, but now it does not print it. thanks again!

Comment: @Ahmed Hadi the method *setText("New Game")* Sets the text of this *Component* to the specified text("New Game" here), whatever is it before. To achieve your requirement you can change *setText()* method into *append("New Game")* method. And try to solve challenge yourself only in this way can you step forward more quick.